# NOT UPLOADED BECAUSE (conn=4254387) Duplicate entry '1097894' for key 'PRIMARY' ; EXCEPTION OCCURED ON ROW NO. 2

Tags: spring, session, file-upload, commit, hibernate-query

I am uploading excel file in that file I having data that is getting properly but while saving it showing me an error in my hrpayroll primary key which is generating properly for 2 entries but in the audit table it has the same id no for the primary key for both entry which is throwing error why does happening not getting

I want that hrpayroll table if I am doing 2 entries then there should  be 2 entries with unique id  in hrpayroll audit table

> .internal.SessionImpl)
> SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.pladatechnologies.entity.AuditEntity#1097891],
> EntityKey[com.pladatechnologies.merchantworld.entity.HrPayRoll#310],
> EntityKey[com.pladatechnologies.merchantworld.entity.HrPayRoll#311],
> EntityKey[com.pladatechnologies.merchantworld.entity.HrPayRoll_AUD#component[hrid,REV]{REV=com.pladatechnologies.entity.AuditEntity#1097891,
> hrid=311}],
> EntityKey[com.pladatechnologies.merchantworld.entity.HrPayRoll_AUD#component[hrid,REV]{REV=com.pladatechnologies.entity.AuditEntity#1097891,
> hrid=310}]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[EntityInsertAction[com.pladatechnologies.merchantworld.entity.HrPayRoll_AUD#{REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id
> = 1097891, revisionDate = 9 Nov, 2023 10:35:18 AM), hrid=310}], EntityInsertAction[com.pladatechnologies.merchantworld.entity.HrPayRoll_AUD#{REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id
> = 1097891, revisionDate = 9 Nov, 2023 10:35:18 AM), hrid=311}]] updates=[] deletions=[] orphanRemovals=[]
> collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[]
> collectionUpdates=[] collectionQueuedOps=[]
> unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])

```
@Override
    public String pushToDB(List<Entity> pEntityList) throws SystemException {
        logger.entry();
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String filestatus = "";
        int j = 0;

        try {
            for (Iterator<Entity> it = pEntityList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                HrPayRoll lTHr = (HrPayRoll) it.next();
                j++;
                session.evict(lTHr);
                session.save(lTHr);
                if (j % 300 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
            tx.commit();
            session.flush();
            filestatus = "PROCESSED SUCCESSFULLY";
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            filestatus = "NOT UPLOADED BECAUSE " + e.getCause().getMessage() + " ; EXCEPTION OCCURED ON ROW NO.  " + j;
            return filestatus;
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        logger.exit();
        return filestatus;
    }
```